# I have updated Magefan blog extension to latest version

Tags: magento2

After update when I go to the home page it shows me this error on the bottom of the page. Rest of content on the page is ok.
https://turner-sports.co.uk/
Error filtering template: Invalid block type: Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\PostList\Recent

Comment: seems `Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\PostList\Recent.php` is not there

Comment: check it or if its there then check permission of the file

Comment: Can you update and close your last question?

Comment: Can you if the block file is available or not?

Comment: Can you update your XML file from where you called it in homepage?

Comment: block file is not available as the updated module is under vendor folder.